# Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: KotlinPlatformContainer.supports()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I just updated Android Studio to the latest version 3.5.1 and I know get the following error:

> Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method:
>   KotlinPlatformContainer.supports(). The version of Gradle you connect
>   to does not support that method.
>   To resolve the problem you can
>   change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other
>   information from the model.

I use Kotlin Multiplatform in two of my modules but I don't know if it's related.

Comment: Have the same issue, also in a project that uses Kotlin multiplatform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the issue is known and tracked at:

- Jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-34143
- Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142002567

Comment: With Android Studio `3.5.2` this issue seems to have been solved. I've just updated AS and in the KMP where I had this issue it disappeared.

Answer (score 11):

> Invalidate caches and Restart worked for me

You can also try restarting the IDE first, in case if you're concerned about saving local history and other cached data.